# SQL Server returns different record after insert on linked MS Access table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access

We recently upgraded our backend database from SQL Server 2000 to SQL Server 2008.  Since the switch we've had intermittent (read: impossible to consistently reproduce) and strange problems, but they all seem to be related somehow.

In one case, our users add a new record to a table via a bound form.  **As soon as the record is saved, a different (much older) record is displayed in its place.**  Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to force a requery of the form brings back the newly added record (the form is filtered to show only a single record).

We have managed to isolate a specific instance of the problem based on logging that occurs on a different form.  In the BeforeUpdate event of the form a timestamp is correctly filled in on the record being inserted.  In the AfterUpdate event of the same form a history record is created in another table that includes the Autonumber ID of the first table.  **About 1 in 10 of these history records is created with the wrong Autonumber ID.**

Has anyone witnessed this sort of behavior or have any explanation for it?

**EDIT:** Additional thoughts:

- the backend database is part of a merge replication
- the Access front-end versions are 2000 and 2002 (other versions not tested)
- one post I read suggested Access uses `@@IDENTITY` behind the scenes to get the newly added record back from SQL Server
- the problem occurs using both the `{SQL Server}` ODBC driver and the `{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}` ODBC driver to connect to the backend table
- compatibility level is set to 80 (SQL Server 2000 level compatibility)

**EDIT:** SQL Profiler Trace results:

I ran SQL Profiler and confirmed that Access is indeed using `SELECT @@IDENTITY` behind the scenes to return the newly inserted record.  I confirmed this is happening with MS Access 2000, 2002 (XP), and 2007 front-ends.  It is also happening whether the tables are linked using the `{SQL Server}` ODBC Driver or the `{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}` ODBC driver.

I should emphasize that Access is using `SELECT @@IDENTITY` *behind the scenes*.  As far as I know there is no way to force Access to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY`.  Too bad, though, because that seems like it would be the simplest fix.

Comment: what does it mean "wrong Autonumber ID"?

Comment: For instance, one newly added record had an auto-generated ID of 210272.  In the `AfterUpdate` event we insert that value into a history table.  So the history table record should have had a value of 210272.  However, the value that got inserted was 1077, which was the auto ID of a much older record.

Comment: AutoNumber is to MS Access as IDENTITY is to SQL Server

Comment: Difficult to troubleshoot with the information given. However, I can think of two places to look: 1. ensure the tables in question have a primary key (and that Access knows about them). 2. Ensure you are not making any assumptions about sort order. SQL Server provides zero guarantees about row order unless you specify an Order By.

Comment: Preaching to the choir.  It's pretty difficult to troubleshoot with the info I have.  1.  The tables do have primary keys and Access recognizes them correctly.  2.  No assumptions about sort order.  The issue seems to be with the underlying implementation in MS Access.  I read one post on another forum that suggested Access may be using `@@IDENTITY` behind the scenes to get the newly inserted record back from SQL Server.  I should add that the problem is occurring in Access versions 2000 and 2002.  Haven't been able to test other versions.

Comment: Have you tried running a SQL profiler trace to get a view of the commands that the Access client is running?

Comment: Have you tried it with A2007 or A2010?

Comment: @David:  I don't have a copy of A2010, but it failed in A2007 the same way.  See the latest EDIT in my post.

Comment: I think it would be good for somebody with the appropriate environment to try it with A2010, because one of the key new features of A2010 means that your ACCDB *also* needs the equivalent of SCOPE_IDENTITY(). That is because the table-level data macros introduced in A2010 can function like triggers, and @@IDENTITY could return the wrong value. Maybe MS addressed that and made sure that it never returns the wrong value, but I don't know that for certain. I've raised this question many times and nobody seems to know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of looking around (mostly off the link included as "more" by garik), shows that you're stuck with the behavior--it's an Access/SQL Server communication bug. **However**, there's a workaround described at [this link](http://jagbarcelo.blogspot.com/search/label/identity).

It's way too complicated for me to reproduce in detail, and *very* well explained there, but basicly you save @@IDENTITY to variable at the start trigger, then do a phony `#temp` insert to spoof the value back to what you want returned at the end.

Comment: Seems to me that doing your inserts with an sproc is not that big of a hardship, don't you think?

Comment: @David: The problem is that you can't use bound forms.  Access relies on @@IDENTITY to get the newly inserted record back from SQL Server, but because of the well-documented shortcomings of @@IDENTITY this causes problems.

Comment: Under VB6, which is actually a stronger suit for me than Access, I did _all_ DB access using sprocs, and didn't screw around with bound forms _at all_. Much cleaner, IMHO. Yes, there's more code to write/read, but you _know_ what's happening.

Comment: @mwolfe02: I don't do most record additions in a bound form in the first place -- I tend to use an unbound form to collect the required fields, insert the record, then load the resulting new record into the main data edit/display form. An SPROC works great in that scenario.

Comment: @David: Do you use that same paradigm for subforms, as well?  If so, what approach do you take?  Put unbound fields on the parent form to add records to the subform?

Comment: This is basically the crux of my solution.  See my answer for the unabridged version.

Comment: For continuous/datasheet subforms, I generally don't allow editing at all, and use a detail form for creating/editing the data. Sometimes that's an unbound popup form, sometimes it's a bound subform on the same form as the list subform.

Answer (score 3):

Use SCOPE_IDENTITY instead of @@IDENTITY.

> Since @@IDENTITY returns the last
>   identity values generated in current
>   session, if there are some triggers in
>   any tables manipulated in current
>   session, we will get unexpected value.
>   In order to get the required value,
>   please use SCOPE_IDENTITY. This
>   function will return value inserted
>   only within the current scope.

[more](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreplication/thread/c7c82024-f142-4915-a890-9c0854a409ec)

Comment: +1 for the link.  It got me (and Roland) pointed in the right direction.  Unfortunately switching to using SCOPE_IDENTITY is not an option since the call to @@IDENTITY is hard-coded in Access.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's not "hard-coded in Access" but in Jet/ACE (or the ODBC driver -- it's unclear which is to blame).

Answer (score 2):

Whew!  What a harrowing experience that was.  First off, a quick note to the MS Access team:

> If you haven't already done it for A2010, take five minutes and do a find and replace on your codebase replacing every instance of `SELECT @@IDENTITY` with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` where it interfaces with SQL Server.  This is a good example of where an open-source project would have been fixed a long time ago.... But I digress.

My apologies upfront for what will be a very lengthy post.  I'm going to try and record all of the knowledge I've gained over the past week trying to fix this vexing problem.  My original post summed up the behavior I was seeing.  Please read that first for full context.

The thing that gave me the most fits with this problem was its seemingly random nature.  We would do an insert and it would fail.  Then we would do fifty more and they would all succeed.  Then the next day we would do an insert and it would fail again.  We'd then do ten more and they would all succeed.  Then a few hours later one would fail again.  And on and on.

The problem was being caused by merge replication.  When a table gets added as an article to a merge replication publication, several triggers are automatically generated to manage the replication.  This was not a problem for us when we used merge replication in SQL Server 2000.  However, these triggers were modified starting with SQL Server 2005.  The specific modification that caused the problem is in these lines of code that were auto-generated in the insert trigger for the affected tables:

```
select @newgen = NULL
    select top 1 @newgen = generation from [dbo].[MSmerge_genvw_8D1ADB4453634BF39DA4AA582FE18F78] with (rowlock, updlock, readpast) 
    where art_nick = 14201004    and genstatus = 0
        and  changecount <= (1000 - isnull(@article_rows_inserted,0))
if @newgen is NULL
begin
    insert into [dbo].[MSmerge_genvw_8D1ADB4453634BF39DA4AA582FE18F78] with (rowlock)
        (guidsrc, genstatus, art_nick, nicknames, coldate, changecount)
         values   (newid(), 0, @tablenick, @nickbin, @dt, @article_rows_inserted)
    select @error = @@error, @newgen = @@identity    
    if @error<>0 or @newgen is NULL
        goto FAILURE
end
else
begin
    -- now update the changecount of the generation we go to reflect the number of rows we put in this generation
    update [dbo].[MSmerge_genvw_8D1ADB4453634BF39DA4AA582FE18F78]  with (rowlock)
        set changecount = changecount + @article_rows_inserted
        where generation = @newgen
    if @@error<>0 goto FAILURE
end
```

Here's what's going on in the above code snippet.  SQL Server is checking to see if there is an open row in the [MSmerge_genhistory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178533.aspx) table (`MSmerge_genvw_8D1ADB4453634BF39DA4AA582FE18F78` is a system view into that table).  If there is an open row (`genstatus = 0`) and the number of inserts plus the change count does not exceed 1000 then the counter gets incremented.  **But if there is not an open row a new one gets inserted.**  Which resets the `@@IDENTITY` variable.  Mass hysteria ensues.  Cats and dogs, living together. Etc, etc.

To be clear, the fault here is with the Access team for using `@@IDENTITY`, not the SQL Server team for modifying the internals of merge replication.  But, geez, I thought you guys were playing for the same team...

It's worth noting that there is a different row for every table involved in merge replication.  I found the following query most helpful for troubleshooting and understanding what's going on in the genhistory table:

```
SELECT A.name
      ,H.generation
      ,H.art_nick
      ,H.coldate
      ,H.genstatus
      ,H.changecount
  FROM [MSmerge_genhistory] AS H
  INNER JOIN [sysmergearticles] AS A
  ON H.art_nick = A.nickname
  ORDER BY H.generation DESC
```

So what closes a row in the genhistory table?  Well, among other things, every row in the genhistory table is closed whenever a merge agent runs against the database.  Any merge agent.  For any publication.  In our case, we have two separate merge replication publications that run out of the same database.  One merge agent runs hourly; the other runs nightly.

This brings us back to the seemingly random behavior.  I'll annotate my earlier paragraph to explain the behavior:

> We would do an insert and it would fail.  [*New row inserted in genhistory table.*]  Then we would do fifty more and they would all succeed.  [*Row in genhistory table incremented.*]  Then the next day [*after the nightly (and hourly) merge agent ran and closed the row in the genhistory table*] we would do an insert and it would fail again.  [*New row inserted in genhistory table.*]  We'd then do ten more and they would all succeed.  [*Row in genhistory table incremented.*]  Then a few hours later  [*after the hourly merge agent ran and closed the row in the genhistory table*] one would fail again. [*New row inserted in genhistory table.*]

Now that we finally know what's going on we need some way to fix it.  The "right" way would be to use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of `SELECT @@IDENTITY`.  However, that behavior is hard-coded into MS Access so we're forced to put a workaround in SQL Server.  [This link](http://jagbarcelo.blogspot.com/2006/06/problems-with-identity-fields-in-ms.html) provided by @Roland suggests there are three workarounds (see the link for full details).

The third workaround seemed like the best option, but it required multiple shutdowns and restarts of the entire database server plus the author's own additional caveats:

> **Some final words (disclaimer):** As I already stated, this patching procedure is completely unsupported by Microsoft. I shall not be liable for any damage (including, without limitation, damage for loss of business or loss of profits) arising from the use of, or inability to use, this document or any material contained in it, or from any action or decision taken as a result of using this document or any such material. I tested this procedure in my environment, solved the problem and worked as expected. I encourage you to do your own test in virtualised/testing environments first. Before applying any new SQL Server Service Pack that might arise in the future, I suggest to stop the server, restore the original files we copied at step 1 of the procedure, and then follow the instructions of the SP. After the SP is applied (also on subscribers), you can reinit the publications and see if the MS Access error appears again. If so, I suppose you could re-patch the new resource database that the SP might have set in place.

....So after starting and stopping the entire database server I need to make some unsupported changes to core SQL Server behavior plus remember to back out those changes and re-apply them before applying future service packs.  Ummm, no thanks.

I re-read the article several times and realized the key piece of information was [this trick](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.programming/msg/93ec304f6d8e5c4a) to save and restore the `@@IDENTITY` value.  I realized all I needed to do was apply these four lines to every merge insert trigger:

```
declare @identity int, @strsql varchar(128) 
set @identity=@@identity 

set @strsql='select identity (int, ' + cast(@identity as varchar(10)) + ',1) as id into #tmp' 
execute (@strsql)
```

The author's approach was to modify the base merge insert trigger so that the auto-generated triggers were created with the above lines already in place.  This involves editing only one place, but has the drawbacks already mentioned.  My approach was to **modify the triggers after they were already created.**  The only drawback is that you have to do it in a lot more places (ie, once for every table).  But if you could script it somehow.....

The final piece of the puzzle to get it all to work was figuring out what all the current triggers were.  This required the use of two system views: `triggers` and `syscomments`.  I used the `triggers` view to identify the offending triggers (their names all start with 'MSmerge_ins').  I then used the `syscomments` view to get the T-SQL used to create each trigger.  The `syscomments.text` field has a size of 4000.  If the T-SQL exceeds 4000 characters, it gets split into several rows ordered by the `syscomments.colid`.

My final algorithm goes as follows:

1. Cycle through every 'MSMerge_ins' trigger
2. Rebuild the CREATE TRIGGER T-SQL from the syscomments view
3. Run the CREATE TRIGGER T-SQL through a regular expression
4. If the trigger needs to be modified the regex returns an `ALTER TRIGGER` statement
5. If the trigger has already been modified, the regex returns the T-SQL unaltered
6. If an `ALTER TRIGGER` statement is returned it gets executed as a pass-through query that modifies the trigger

I still have to remember to run this code whenever I create (or re-create) a merge replication publication.  Another drawback to my approach is that my regular expression may need to be modified to handle future changes to the automatically generated triggers.  But I can do it on the live server, I don't have to shut anything down, and I'm not agonizing over what I might break in the core functionality.  Decide for yourself what you can and can't live with.

I wrote this to run in MS Access.  To simplify the code, I created links to the `triggers`, `syscomments`, and `sys_tables` views.  The `sys_tables` view is not strictly necessary but I left it in for debugging.

Here's the code:

```
Sub FixInsertMergeTriggers()
Dim SQL As String, TriggerSQL As String, AlterSQL As String
Dim PrevTrigger As String, ProcessTrigger As Boolean

    SQL = "SELECT Ta.Name AS TblName, Tr.Name AS TriggerName, " & _
          "       C.Text, C.Number, C.colid " & _
          "FROM (syscomments AS C " & _
          "INNER JOIN triggers AS Tr ON C.id=Tr.object_id) " & _
          "INNER JOIN sys_tables AS Ta ON Tr.parent_id=Ta.object_id " & _
          "WHERE Tr.name like 'MSmerge_ins*' " & _
          "ORDER BY Tr.name, C.colid"

    With CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(SQL)
        Do
            If .EOF Then
                If Len(PrevTrigger) > 0 Then
                    ProcessTrigger = True
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Else
                ProcessTrigger = (!TriggerName <> PrevTrigger)
            End If
            If ProcessTrigger Then
                If Len(TriggerSQL) > 0 Then
                    AlterSQL = ModifyTrigger(TriggerSQL)
                    If AlterSQL <> TriggerSQL Then
                        ExecPT AlterSQL
                        Debug.Print !TblName; " insert trigger altered"
                    End If
                End If
                TriggerSQL = ""
                If .EOF Then Exit Do
            End If
            TriggerSQL = TriggerSQL & !Text
            PrevTrigger = !TriggerName
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
    Debug.Print "Done."
End Sub

Private Function ModifyTrigger(TriggerSQL As String) As String
Const DeclarationSection As String = "    declare @identity int, @strsql varchar(128)" & vbCrLf & _
                                     "    set @identity=@@identity"
Const ExecuteSection As String = "    set @strsql='select identity (int, ' + cast(@identity as varchar(10)) + ',1) as id into #tmp'" & vbCrLf & _
                                 "    execute (@strsql)"
Dim P As String  'variable that holds our regular expression pattern'

    'Use regular expression to modify the trigger'
    P = P & "(.*)"                            '1. The beginning'
    P = P & "(create trigger)"                '2. Need to change 'CREATE' to 'ALTER''
    P = P & "(.*$)"                           '3. Rest of the first line'
    P = P & "(^\s*declare\s*@is_mergeagent)"  '4. First declaration line'
    P = P & "([\s\S]*)"                       '5. The middle part'
    P = P & "(if\s*@@error[\s\S]*)"           '6. The lines after ...'
    P = P & "(FAILURE:[\s\S]*)"               '7. ... where we add our workaround'

    ModifyTrigger = RegExReplace(P, TriggerSQL, _
                                 "$1ALTER trigger$3" & vbCrLf & _
                                 DeclarationSection & vbCrLf & _
                                 "$4$5" & vbCrLf & _
                                 ExecuteSection & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
                                 "$6$7", , True, True)
End Function

Private Function RegExReplace(SearchPattern As String, TextToSearch As String, ReplacePattern As String, _
                      Optional GlobalReplace As Boolean = True, _
                      Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean = False, _
                      Optional MultiLine As Boolean = False) As String
Dim RE As Object

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
        .MultiLine = MultiLine
        .Global = GlobalReplace
        .IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
        .Pattern = SearchPattern
    End With

    RegExReplace = RE.Replace(TextToSearch, ReplacePattern)
End Function


'Execute pass-through SQL'
Private Sub ExecPT(SQL As String, Optional DbName As String = "MyDB")
Const QName As String = "TemporaryPassThroughQuery"
Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef

    On Error Resume Next
    CurrentDB.QueryDefs.Delete QName
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set qdef = CurrentDB.CreateQueryDef(QName)
    qdef.Connect = "ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};Server=myserver;database=" & DbName & ";Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
    qdef.SQL = SQL
    qdef.ReturnsRecords = False
    CurrentDB.QueryDefs(QName).Execute

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a GREAT answer. Comprehensive & well explained.

Comment: I still think all of this would be solved simply by NOT using bound forms to add records, but instead adding with an SPROC that returns SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of @@IDENTITY.

Comment: One minor quibble: it's not Access that is using @@IDENTITY instead of SCOPE_IDENTITY(), it's Jet/ACE. Indeed, it may be the SQL Server ODBC driver that is to blame. I'd think that a well-written ODBC driver for SQL Server would either default to SCOPE_IDENTITY() or allow the option of doing so.

Comment: I've wondered about whether it was actually the SQL Server ODBC driver that is to blame.  If it is then that is even more inexcusable.  Especially since `@@IDENTITY` is used when the table is connected via the `{SQL Server Native Client 10.0}` ODBC driver (ie, the native client driver for SQL Server 2008).