# Using SPROCs to insert records in SQL Server backend from MS Access frontend

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures

I recently ran into [major problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5956689/sql-server-returns-different-record-after-insert-on-linked-ms-access-table) inserting records into a SQL Server backend from an MS Access frontend because I was using bound forms to do the inserts.  Multiple commenters suggested using SQL Server stored procedures to do the inserts instead.  **How is this normally done?**  Is there general agreement that using SPROCs is a better approach than using bound forms in this scenario?

I have a few specific concerns about using SPROCs:

- **Subforms**: I can easily envision using unbound forms to do inserts via SPROCs for most tables.  However, I don't know how I would approach adding records for subordinate tables.  Via unbound controls on the main form or a pop-up form launched from the main form?  Either of these will be a departure from the interface my users are used to seeing.
- **Version Control**: I have my Access applications under tight version control.  Am I better off using pass-through queries to keep all the program logic in one place or are there other benefits to using stored procedures that are *physically* stored in the backend database?
- **Retrofitting**: Is it practical/worth doing on a large scale (ie, dozens of forms)?

Comment: In regard to the subform issue, I generally don't allow continuous/datasheet subforms to be editable, but I don't think that's the problem here. The issue is ADDS, not EDITS, so it seems to me that your subform will just disallow adds, and you'll have a method for adding a new record via the SPROC and then requerying the subform to load the new record and navigate to it. A popup form or a detail form would work fine (an additional subform bound to the PK of the list subform). What part of that seems to be a problem for you?

Comment: RE: subforms, neither approach is a problem, per se.  But since it would be a different interface than what I've traditionally used I wanted to gauge what the best practices are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored procedures in the database give you the benefit of reusing them outside of your Access application.

Version Control: how are you providing version control on the rest of the sql database objects? If you can put a table under version control, you can put a proc unless all of your table create and update code is in Access.

I wouldn't prioritize retrofitting your forms unless there are data integrity or possibly performance concerns. You can do this over time or when changes/updates are taking place.

Comment: RE: version control of db objects, I'm using the Generate Scripts... wizard in SSMS (Express Edition).  I haven't developed a way to automate the process of version control in SQL Server the way I have in MS Access.  It's a laborious process (relatively speaking) so I don't do it as often or consistently as I should.